# UICollectionView is unintentionally scrolling on button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIButton` added to a `UICollectionViewCell`, with a touch up event calling a method, that brings up a `UIPopoverController`, completely unrelated to the collection view.

Problem is when I press this button, my `UICollectionView` scrolls ever so slightly down. I cannot seem to figure out why. The scrolling actions are called before my button is actually pressed - so my attempts to prevent this form within the method called are futile.

Has anyone experienced this problem, or have any pointers on how to prevent it from happening?

I have tried disabling scrolling on the collection view on touch down, but it appears the touch down also triggers the scrolling - prior to the scroll disable.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, you should `override func touchesShouldCancel`

first, you create new class inherit `UICollectionView`, `UITableView`, `UIScrollView`.

In question, you want cancel in `UICollectionView`.
so you make class inherit `UICollectionCiew`

seond, in `func init` you set property

```
self.delaysContentTouches = false
self.canCancelContentTouches = true
```

final, you override `func touchesShouldCancel` can cancel touch view kind
In question, you want cancel in `UIButton` touch.

you make inherit class below code

```
import UIKit

class TouchCancelCollectionView: UICollectionView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.delaysContentTouches = false
        self.canCancelContentTouches = true
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {

        if view.isKind(of: UIButton.self) {
            return true
        }

        return super.touchesShouldCancel(in: view)
    }
}
```

and use it!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to use answer from [홍성호](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14183712/%ED%99%8D%EC%84%B1%ED%98%B8) and it was almost correct, but you must return `false` for view you don't want tracked.
My implementation is for `UIScrollView`, but it's similar for `UICollectionView`.

```
final class NewScrollView: UIScrollView {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    delaysContentTouches = false
    canCancelContentTouches = true
}

@available(*, unavailable)
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
    if view is NameOfYourView {
        return false
    }

    return super.touchesShouldCancel(in: view)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, I think this line of code could help you out.

```
yourCollectionView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

The problem is when there is a touch on the collectionView, the system doesn't know you are trying to click the button or scroll the view, so Apple gives scrolling higher priority. Hope this answer is right.

Feeling good to answer a question asked one year ago :)

Comment: This problem is still unsolved for me a year later. I was excited to see your post, but unfortunately it did not solve my issue. Still a little bounce in the collection view when I touch the UIButton.